# How can I tell rails to use xhtml strict instead of transitional?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, xhtml-1.0-strict

So when you use scaffolding Rails will kick out some layouts that are xhtml transitional. I prefer strict.

Is there some setting somewhere to do this?  Or shall I continue to edit the doctype in the layouts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're supposed to replace scaffolding with your own view code. That's why it's called scaffolding—it's just to get you started.

Comment: I understand, and I do edit the views it kicks out ... just tired of replacing the stuff above the <body> every time, thought there might be a config setting somewhere.